# Formula containing single and multiple results

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

[image]

My report uses two tables. The first table has a single value, and second table has multiple. How can I make a formula that shows a single value from the first table, and sum of multiple values from second table?

Data from these two tables comes from Excel upload. So, some of the data in these two tables don't have matching value. Some data have matching value. I want both of these data in report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can calculate it in your SQL query, something like this:

```
select 
  [Code], [Name], 
  sum(case when ord = 1 then amount else 0 end) as Amount1,
  sum(case when ord = 2 then amount else 0 end) as Amount2
from (
  select [Code], [Name], [Amount1] amount, 1 ord
  from table1
  union all
  select [Code], [Name], [Amount2], 2
  from table2
) t
group by
  [Code], [Name];
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2402/3)**